# Odd Behavior for Rest API lookup Column filtering

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, filter

I've recently been working on a project requiring Rest Queries against a large SharePoint list (5000+ items) and ran into an interaction I can't quite find an explanation for.

The scenario is that I have my main list with 5000+ items in it. This list has a lookup field I wish to filter by during my Rest query. The lookup column in the main list is indexed and all columns in the list the lookup column references are also indexed.

When filtering on the Id of the lookup fields the query returns expected results as long as the query doesn't return more than 5000 items.

But when filtering on any other column from the lookup fields I'm hit with  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException even if the query would return the same results as the Id filter.

To give an example of queries:

This one works:

```
"/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('List')/Items?&$select=LookUpField/Id&$expand=LookUpField&$filter=LookUpField/Id eq SomeNumber"
```

This one returns Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException

```
"/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('List')/Items?&$select=LookUpField/IndexedColumn&$expand=LookUpField&$filter=LookUpField/IndexedColumn eq Something"
```

Are there any differences between the Id column and other indexed columns that would cause this behavior?

Comment: You have extended this another column along with lookup?

Comment: Your environment is SharePoint online or on-premise?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Yes I have.

Comment: @Mihir I'm working on 2016 on premise